Android and WhatsApp support for multi user use on a device in a family with several sim cards but a single shared phone
Suppose a family shares a phone.
Suppose the Android device has a dual sim card slot.
Is it possible for one family member to use one sim card and join that sim card to their WhatsApp account
while the other family member switches user on the multiuser Android system and under the other user configures their WhatsApp account to use the other sim card in the other sim card slot?
The family may be too poor to own two phones for two different family members, but may be able to afford two sim cards to manage contacts separately.
I wonder whether under such a scenario the telephony support would support special messages to indicate that the phone was being used by the other user, or, alternatively, let you use the other sim card for WhatsApp so that the contact may be contacted on WhatsApp on the other sim.
Ideally, if more then two users were present, each could have a sim card and they could borrow the phone from each other, inserting their own sim card each time.
I wonder what the Android operating system and WhatsApp have done to support these kind of scenarios.
Thanks.
